# how to disable javascript in chrome by code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

we kown that chrome provide us the method to disable js in web developer Panel.
but i want to disable js from chrome extension by the interface if chrome provide
if chrome dont allow developer do this , 
if i can get the list of the  element banned loading when set disabled in panel.
thank you

Comment: Do you want to disable it through the Settings menu or from a Chrome extension?

Comment: And more important - Why? I did not see it here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions.html

Comment: Oh ok. I thought so due to the tag but the question's wording was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: oh  sorry.thank you for your reminding

Comment: Check out the [`chrome.contentSettings`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings.html) API.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to stop a particular script from loading (is that right?), consider using Chrome's `webRequest` API to stop it from even being loaded in the first place. [The API reference contains an example of how to cancel a request.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#examples) (Note that the first example is for demonstration purposes; the second example is more efficient if you know the URL in advance.)